# Dynamically cast IEnumerable to IQueryable or dynamically call AsQueryable with LINQ Expressions

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

I am creating LINQ query dynamically, and I am doing OK so far.

But I am stuck where I thought I wouldn't be. At a certain point in building that query, I need to access EnityCollection of an entity. Something like this:

```
Expression collection = Expression.Property(entity, typeof(EntityType).GetProperty("CollectionOfRelatedEntities"));
```

Then, I would call "Where" LINQ method upon that collection:

```
MethodCallExpression AfterWhere = Expression.Call(
                        typeof(Queryable),
                        "Where",
                        new Type[] { typeof(RelatedEntity) },
                        collection,
                        Expression.Lambda<Func<RelatedEntity, bool>>(predicate, new ParameterExpression[] { paramOfRelatedEntity }));
```

And normally that would work. In this case it won't because collection is IEnumerable and I need it to be IQueryable in order "Where" to work.

I tried this:

```
Expression.Convert(collection, typeof(IQueryable<RelatedEntity>);
```

but it says unable to cast because EntityCollection doesn't implement IQueryable.

I statically use AsQueryable to achieve what i need here, so i tried mimicking that dynamically:

```
Expression.Call(collection, typeof(EntityCollection<RelatedEntity>).GetMethod("AsQueryable"));
```

but I get null reference exception. I can't reach it via reflection. This AsQueryable method is extension method, it is static, defined in Queryable class, so i tried:

```
Expression.Call(collection, typeof(Queryable).GetMethod("AsQueryable", BindingFlags.Static));
```

Same result: "Value cannot be null".

I am reaching my limits here, and I am fresh out of ideas.

So, I am asking you:

How can I dynamically cast IEnumerable to IQueryable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to get the method this way:

```
var method = typeof(Queryable).GetMethod(
    "AsQueryable",
    BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, 
    null, 
    new [] { typeof(IEnumerable<RelatedEntity>)}, 
    null);
```

Then, you should be able to construct a call to that method like this:

```
Expression.Call(method, collection);
```

The problem with your code was that BindingFlags are tricky to use. If you specify any BindingFlags - like BindingFlags.Static - then you **also** have to explicitly say whether you want BindingFlags.Public or BindingFlags.NonPublic.

Then the second problem is that there are two AsQueryable methods - a generic one and a non-generic one. Providing the array of type arguments resolves that ambiguity.

Comment: Just tried it. No luck. I still get null. I tried with new Type[0] as fourth parameter, and I tried just the way you wrote, but I still get null. I also checked MSDN and this is signature of AsQueryable: public static IQueryable AsQueryable(this IEnumerable source);

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, forgot IEnumerable<>. But now, when I try to use that method like: Expression.Call(collection, typeof(Queryable).GetMethod("AsQueryable", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null, new [] { typeof(IEnumerable<RelatedEntity>) }, null)) compiler says: "Static method requires null instance, non-static method requires non-null instance.". Extension methods are called on instance methods, right? So, how do i overcome this obsticle?

Comment: You are correct all the way. It took me a while to understand what you wrote, but now, it's clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> "And normally that would work. In this case it won't because collection is IEnumerable and I need it to be IQueryable in order "Where" to work."

No, you don't. For an enumerable, use `Enumerable.Where` instead of `Queryable.Where`.

```
var query =
    from customer in Context.Customers
    where customer.Id == YourCustomerId // 1
    select new
    {
        Customer = customer,
        OrderCount = customer.Orders.Where(order => order.IsOpen).Count() // 2
    };
```

The first "where" resolves to `Queryable.Where`, but the second doesn't, that's `Enumerable.Where`. That isn't a problem or inefficient, because the whole expression is part of a subquery, so it will *still* be sent to the query provider and (f.e.) translated to SQL.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I changed type of Where call from Queryable to Enumerable, and did the same for every consequent LINQ call, and it's working like a peach. I also managed to make it work with calling AsQueryable before passing it to where.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I got it:

First, get the method via reflection as Igor said:

```
MethodInfo mi = typeof(Queryable).GetMethod("AsQueryable", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null, new [] { typeof(IEnumerable<RelatedEntity>) }, null);
```

then, I used different version of Expression.Call to overcome static/instance mismatch:

```
Expression buff = Expression.Call(mi, new[] { collection });
```

and finally cast it to a typed AsQueryable:

```
Expression final = Expression.Convert(buff, typeof(IQueryable<RelatedEntity>));
```